# Large ViewState value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am building an application in ASP.NET 2.0 and the value for the view state is huge:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTExNz...
```

The value contains 535,000 characters. Is this normal? How can I make it smaller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look into [enabling ASP.NET tracing](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19355/The-Basics-of-NET-Tracing.htm) for your web pages - that will tell you what controls are storing how much in view state. You can then go and disable view state for controls that you know aren't using it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem was a dropdown list that was populated from a database. Dont know why it had a huge viewstate.

Comment: I recommend the approach of programming without viewstate; enable and use only if required by the form and/or controls.  In this case you might want to evaluate if viewstate is necessary for this particular control.  If not sure, disable it at the control level, see what breaks, then re-enable it.  Viewstate size may be multiples of the control's actual data size, so you should populate data sparingly - only include what's needed.

Answer (score 6):

ViewState can grow ugly on you. Basically I would say that the problem is that ViewState is enabled by default on everything, and a *lot* of things don't need it to be. The most basic example would be Label objects.

Try disabling ViewState where you find it unnecessary (EnableViewState is the property you're looking for).

Comment: Would it depend on objects per page or in the entire application?

Comment: It would depend on the objects in that page.

Comment: Might be worth adding an example: `<asp:Label ID="productName" EnableViewState="false" Text="[Product Name]" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 2):

If you write a bit of code, you can store view state in your server instead of sending it through the network for a round trip. Also you can compress it to save space/bandwidth and load time.

[Here](http://rakasuniverse.info/blog/2010/07/06/asp-net-reduce-page-size-bandwidth-usage-page-load-delay-by-storing-view-state-on-server/) is something I wrote about it some time back.